# PostgreSQL - Find the difference between the minimum and 2nd from minimum times (timezonez) for each user

Tags: sql, postgresql

| Time | user_id |
| --- | --- |
| 12:00 | 123 |
| 14:21 | 459 |
| 13:45 | 123 |
| 18:21 | 459 |
| 17:28 | 459 |
| 13:43 | 123 |
| 11:21 | 459 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` to get the rows with the two smallest times, then calculate `max(time) - min(time)` to get the difference between the two, with `group by user_id`. No need for a join:

```
select user_id,
max(time) - min(time) as diff
from (select *, row_number() over(partition by user_id order by time) rn from table_name) t
where rn <= 2
group by user_id;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=559cddd2a1879a2f400fd00149ff79d9)

Answer (score 0):

If you do a `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY time)` in a cte, you'll get an incrementing counter in order of time, that restarts from 1 for every different user

If you then join the cte to itself on `a.user_id = b.user_id and a.rn = 1 and b.rn=2` it will put the Min time and the next-Min time on the same row which makes digging the times easy

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY time) rn FROM t
)
SELECT *
FROM 
  cte a 
  INNER JOIN cte b ON a.user_id = b.user_id and a.rn = 1 and b.rn=2
```

a.time is the min, b.time is the next-min - then whatever you want to do to diff them.. I'm not really clear on what data type they are but I'm sure that once they're on the same row of a resultset you can do whatever you need to them to diff them